# iphone: AVAudioRecorder recording always return FALSE

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioRecorder to record sound, but I have a problem.

After calling the method [recorder record], the value of recorder.recording always returns FALSE, so that I can not stop the recording.

I am using XCode 4.2 with iOS 5, my iPad is ipad 2 on iOS 5 also.

This is my code:

```
    self.currentFileName = [GlobalRecording newRecordingFileName];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[GlobalRecording recordingDirectory]    stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentFileName]];
NSError *err = nil;

AVAudioRecorder *aRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordingSettings error:&err];
if( err ){
    NSLog(@"could not create a recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
    return;
}

self.startRecordingTime = [NSDate date];
recordingLength = 0.0f;

//  setup recorder and start recording
[aRecorder setDelegate:self];
aRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[aRecorder record];

self.recorder = aRecorder;
BOOL test = recorder.recording;
[aRecorder release];
```

Comment: [aRecorder record] returns boolean on whether it is success or failed. Can you check if your record call is success?

Comment: The value return from [aRecorder record] is FALSE. That means it does not success. is my code wrong?

Comment: can you check this what happen ?
BOOL prepared=[aRecorder prepareToRecord];
    if(prepared)
    {
       
        [aRecorder record];
    }

Answer (score 3):

try using AVAudioSession after [audioRecord prepareToRecord]

```
    NSError *err = nil;
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];

// route to speaker
UInt32 ASRoute = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(ASRoute), &ASRoute);

if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
}

[audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
```

Answer (score 2):

An audio session is the intermediary between your app and iOS used to configure your app’s audio behavior. Upon launch, your app automatically gets a singleton audio session.

so activate your session before start recording

For Swift 3.0

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("could not set session category")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        do {
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("could not make session active")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
self.recorder.record() // recorder is my AVAudioRecorder
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar symptom, because I was using a library to playback that was resetting `AVAudioSession` global settings.  I needed to reset the settings each time I wanted to record.

```
do {
  try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
  try session.setActive(true)
} catch {
  return error
}
```

The library I'm using resets it to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlay`. Sure would be nice if there was an error to access other than `false` to let you know what caused the failure of `record()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also seeing a delay when you invoke the record method? I'm seeing an issue when using iOS5 on iPhone4 hardware where the record method has a 3-4 second delay and occasionally will fail to start recording. I'm calling prepareToRecord as recommended with the same issue.

This is not an issue on iOS4/iPhone4 or iOS5/iPhone4S...so it seems to be an issue running the new OS on older hardware.

Comment: Any resolution to this?  I'm having the same issue with the same device/software versions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on Simulator, and after investigation I found that it was because my computer didn't set up any audio input sources. Once I connected an input source (e.g., AirPod) and `record()` finally returned `true` and started to work. Sadly, `record()` never gives any error to indicate this type of failure.